# Oracle APEX, Column populating t1001 on add row when it is both master column and primary key in detail grid

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-19.1

I have a Master-detail grid

Master primary key - empid
Detail primary key - empid, deptid

When I add a new row in detail IG, the empid is populating with t1001 instead of the master grid's empid value.

Is there any way we can fetch the master empid into detail empid.

Comment: The t1001 is the primary key that is assigned in the IG model for rows that have not been saved to the database yet. Please provide more info. how is the primary key generated - trigger ? Also, any business reason you're using the composite primary key ? Why not just use a surrogate key for the detail table since the relationship is defined by the foreign key relationship ?

Comment: 'How is the primary key generated ' - Since it is also a primary key for another table, the primary key takes the value of master record. I could make use of rowid, but we have business requirement to use the primary keys of the table only.

Comment: If you save the detail row - what happens ?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the Primary Key flag for the Detail IG.
Apex IG auto-populates PKs like t1001 only when we have Primary Key flag enabled.